# QT - Drag and Drop - Creating Custom Graphic object on Custom Scene in Drop's place

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, scene

I created simple d&d drop - soemthing like QT Creator menu - ListView on the side and DragScene (my own subclass of QGraphicsScene). I want to created new Graphic item ( i already got my custo mclasses for it) to be added there - in place where i dropped it (Something similar how QT Designer works). I created my own class:

DragScene.h

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMimeData>

#include "CustomObj.h"

class DragScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    DragScene(QObject* parent = 0);

 protected:
     void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
};
```

DragScene.cpp

```
#include "DragScene.h"

DragScene::DragScene(QObject* parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
}

void DragScene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
}

void DragScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
}

void DragScene::dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
}

void DragScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
        CustomObj* newObject = new CustomObj(0,0,50,50);
        newObject->setPos(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y()); //(1)
        this->addItem(newObject);

        qDebug() <<"New object";
}
```

Now, when i drag my itemy - it appears, but always @ point (0,0). I dont know why this is. What is even stranger - i added:

```
qDebug() << "Moving : "<< event->pos();
```

in

```
void CustomObj::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
```

and i saw how it was canging whiel i was moving it:

> Moving : QPointF(17, 29)
>
> Moving : QPointF(17, 29)
>
> Moving : QPointF(18, 29)
>
> Moving : QPointF(18, 30)
>
> Moving : QPointF(17, 30)
>
> Moving : QPointF(18, 29)
>
> Moving : QPointF(17, 30)
>
> Moving : QPointF(17, 30)
>
> Moving : QPointF(18, 31)
>
> Moving : QPointF(17, 30)
>
> ...

And it's from first move after creating it - it's like those parameters i get @ start are tottaly different type then those object use.

**Objective 1** : *I want to initialize CustomObjs to make them appear where i dropped my item from List.* (But so far - position fro mevent is always (0,0) and on first move of this object caused by mouse - i can see from qDebug() that position wasn't (0,0), but still every element appear in the same place.)
**Objective 2** : *I want to control them to stay in the scene (be unable to pass its boundries)*

Comment: Do the `event->pos().x()` and `event->pos().y()` really return **0, 0** ?

Comment: Yes - when i read drop event in my scene it's always (0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objective 1**

Use the `QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent::​scenePos()` to get the right position in the scene coordinates.

**Objective 2**

```
CustomObj* newObject = new CustomObj(0,0,50,50);
newObject->setPos(event->scenePos());

QRectF sceneArea = scene->sceneRect(); // QGraphicsScene::sceneRect()
QRectF itemArea = newObject->sceneBoundingRect();

// Test if your item bounding rectangle completely lies inside the scene rectangle.
if (sceneArea.contains(itemArea))
    scene->addItem(newObject);
else
    qDebug() << "Outside the scene";
```

Comment: @2 - Thx, worked out fine, but i meant while moving object - not adding it. Do i always suppose to use scenePos while operating on those objects? If i'm goingto save it in file or add zoom in/out options - are those still best picks?

Comment: `QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent::​scenePos()` give you a position in the scene coordinates, while `QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent::​pos()` is position in the viewport (widget) coordinates. When you are setting a position of the QGraphicsSceneItem you have to use the scene coordinates. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html